# How do I reverse the redstone door so it starts in close position?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to make a hidden door in Minecraft.
I have pressure plates set up to open the door, but since the door starts in open mode, when I use the pressure plates, it closes and then opens.
How do I get it to start in closed position?

What I have tried: I added a lever and that made it start in closed position but then my pressure plates would not work.

What I want is the pressure plates to be the openers for the door so that you would have to run over the pressure plates to get through the door using the tiny window opportunity created by the plates.

Comment: Are you using a standard door, or a piston door? Standard doors start in closed mode, so either your positioning of your door is terrible, or your mistaken, or your not giving enough information.

Answer (score 9):

You need to make a [inverter](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Logic_circuit#NOT_Gate) (a NOT gate), just run the redstone up to a block then place a torch on the opposite side. When the redstone is off on the input it will make it on on the output

[image]

See the Minecaft wiki link above for diagrams for other styles of inverters.

Answer (score 0):

[image: ***this might work. By the way the repeaters are pointing towards the block the redstone torch is on(for the picture a barrier)***]

this might work. By the way the repeaters are pointing towards the block the redstone torch is on(for the picture a barrier) how this works is the redstone torch powers the door forcing it to stay closed. The repeaters turn the redstone torch on and off. The redstone connects the pressure plate to the repeaters

> NOTE: works with buttons, levers, /testfor, tripwire hooks, etc...